# Oracle WebGate Single Sign On

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, sign

I'm doing a high level investigation into single sign on with oracle.

As I understand it the webgate communicates with the OAM server to authenticate the user.

Will this still work if the Webgate and OAM server are in different domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will still work if WebGate and OAM Server are in different domain. OAM Server opens a OAP channel (port) for communication with WebGate and that must be accessible to WebGate.

HTH